# Formatting JSON data with "ObjectMapper"

Tags: java, json, spring, datetime, localdate

I have a field:

```
@NotNull
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date;
```

But when I get data with JSON format - it is another:

```
"date":{"year":2020,"month":"JANUARY","monthValue":1,"dayOfMonth":6,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":6,"era":"CE","chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"},"leapYear":true}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: show us the rest of your code please

Comment: If my memory serves, I solved this by disabling `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` on the object mapper.

Comment: Would you please check your import and let know which lib JsonFormat belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom serializer/deserializer for it.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate date;
```

This article goes into more detail on how you can create these classes - https://kodejava.org/how-to-format-localdate-object-using-jackson/